# Postgres SIZE limits on hobby-dev plan

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

[Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans) say "enforced row limits of 10,000 rows for hobby-dev plan" but what does that mean in terms of size? How many Gb is that?

Other providers are clear on their free tier limits: Google Firestore 1Gb, FaunaDB 5Gb, AWS DynamoDB 25Gb.

How much space does Heroku Postgres allow under the hobby-dev plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a limit to disk size of the data stored, only the number of rows for the hobby tier of Heroku Postgres. I have a strong suspicion though that if this is abused you'll probably hear from them, or the database will simply be shut down.

Comment: Thanks @RangerRanger for clarifying that. Wish the Heroku docs were more clear about it.